# on other Page CustomListTile usage

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use CustomListTile Widget for format my JSON file on other Page.

This structure uses Future Builder and I can't see any error

```
child: FutureBuilder<Articles>(
          future: _futureArticles,
          builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final articles = snapshot.data?.data;

              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: articles!.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                    customListTile(articles[index], context),
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return NewsError(
                errorMessage: '${snapshot.hasError}',
              );
            } else {
              return const NewsLoading(
                text: 'Loading...',
              );
            }
          },
        ),
```

on the other Page I have a CustomListTile Widget. I have imported the FutureBuilder page already

```
Widget customListTile(index article, BuildContext context) {
  return InkWell(
    onTap: () {
      Icons.message;
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => article(
                    index: article,
                  )));
    },
    child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black12,
              blurRadius: 3.0,
            ),
          ]),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 200.0,
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(

              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(article[index].imageUrl!),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 8.0,
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.red,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            ),
            child: Text(
              article.category.name,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 8.0,
          ),
          Text(
            article.title,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 16.0,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

but VS Code highlight **index** and this is not working

```
Widget customListTile(index article, BuildContext context) {
```

Where I am doing a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `index`(`index article`) is no type. As far as I can see you need the index for Lists, to tell the app which "item" of the list it should take. If you want to retrieve an item of a list, you have to call the name of the list and then in `[]`"the number" of the place, where the item is in the list. The type of "number" you need is of type `int`. So your argument `index`, should be of type `int`.
Try this:

```
Widget customListTile(int index, BuildContext context) {
```